# Gallery shows 404 on other languages

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, nextgen-gallery

I have **multilingual** site. I've inserted album with galleries into page. Galleries are shown correctly only when I'm on the base lang page.

E.g. `www.site.com/gallery_page` But when lang segment is added to url, `www.site.com/ru/gallery_page`, and I'm clicking on some gallery (e.g `www.site.com/ru/gallery_page/nggalery/album-1/gallery-1`) **404 error** page is returned.

I'm using **qTranslate-X** as a multilang plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As author of plugin says, "qTranslate is not compatible with NextGEN Gallery and  WPML is recommended in its place".